# Spring Boot configuração erro: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Olá!

Estou obtendo o seguinte StackTrace abaixo quando inicio o Tomcat com meu projeto Web depois de fazer as configurações com Spring Boot. Depois que criei as seguintes classes abaixo, estou tendo esse erro.

**ERRO**

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:288)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:278)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:351)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:272)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:338)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    ... 33 more
```

**Pacote com Classes de Configuração do Spring: com.rsw.configuration**

**Classe DataBaseConnection**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DataBaseConnection {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Classe ApplicationConfiguration**

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-config.xml" });
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }
}
```

**Classe ApplicationInitializer**

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ApplicationConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

**Arquivo application.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gfinan
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = 
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
```

**POM.xml**

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.5</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Spring BOOT-->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javax - Jsf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql-Conector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>restauranteWeb</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>restaurante</finalName>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

A versão do spring que você declara no **properties** não é compativel com o Spring boot 1.4.

Atualize para 4.3 ou superior.

Recomendo:

```
<spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
```